# <item> offset behavior not what I expected

Tags: android, xml, offset, shapes, layer-list

I have this drawable XML file. The target is to draw two concentric frames, the outer being yellow and the inner being red. And I want it all done in XML, using shapes, not in code and not using bitmaps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <stroke android:width="15dp" android:color="@color/Yellow"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="@color/Red"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

This generates this screen (ignore the 3 rectangles inside, just the framing yellow and red rectangles)

[image]

This shows that the yellow frame is drawn OK and red frame is drawn with a 5dp left offset.
My final red frame should have offest on all its sides

```
    <item android:left="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:bottom="5dp">
```

See what happens when I add just one other offset

```
    <item android:left="5dp" android:top="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="@color/Red"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
```

[image]

The same happens if I add all the required offsets.
This not what I expected, according to [the documentation on item offset](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)
What is happening here?
How can I make the red frame shrink by 5dp as I wanted to?

**EDIT**
I played a little with the offsets an found something wierd, using one negative offset of 5dp, see what I get:

```
    <item android:left="-5dp" android:top="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:bottom="5dp">
```

[image]

It only works with negative values `<= -5dp`.  For negative values `> 5dp` it still does not show the frames, as before.

I strongly feel that the reason for all this behavior can only be one out of two:

- I am grossely misunderstaning how the offset values should be used
- It is a buggy behavior (in which case I would like confirmation so I can report it)

Comment: How do you use that `layer-list` and where did you tested/see the described behavior(emulator/specific phone/specific version)?

Comment: @Luksprog The layer list is the `android:background` of an `ImageView` element in a `FrameLayout`. My project is defined from min version 14 to version 17 and executed on AVD target android-15 running intel's HAXM. Sadly my tablet was stolen a few weeks ago and right now I have no real device to test it on.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior(tested using your conditions) so I'm assuming is something else in your code. If you can provide a simple sample reproducing the behavior post it here or report it as a bug.

Comment: @Luksprog I created anew project from scratch with only the frames for  layout and it worked as expected. So the problem must be somwhere else, my real project is much more complex and uses libraries, with layouts and code all over, I'll have to identify what in my setup is causing this. If I do I will post the answer here.